# How to convert exp() symbol from an expression to a numerical value?

Tags: python, sympy

I have this code:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
f = exp(x)+exp(x-0.1)+exp(-x-1)    #Random Function
d = diff(f,x)    #Differentiate f w.r.t x
a = d.subs({x:2})    #Put x=2
print(a)
```

The output is:

```
-exp(-3) + 1.90483741803596*exp(2)
```

But here, I don't want exp() to appear as a symbol. Rather, I want the numerical value of it.

Expected Output:

```
14.025163472842058
```

How do I replace the exp() symbol to fetch the numerical value?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Documentation for it: [Documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html)

But essentially `a` is an expression-object, in order to evaluate it you have to call something like `evalf` on it. Since you already did the substitution step you just need to call `a.evalf()` to get a number.

There are also other methods but those might need other dependencies.

For Example:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
f = exp(x)+exp(x-0.1)+exp(-x-1)    #Random Function
d = diff(f,x)    #Differentiate f w.r.t x
a = d.subs({x:2})    #Put x=2
print(a.evalf()) # prints: 14.0251634728421
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps :)